# Spring MVC - calling methods in @ResponseBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am Spring MVC beginner and  I want to call rest   in @ResponseBody. My external node server doesn't react on that method. I don't got message about request in my server console. Without UserRest it works. I would be grateful for your help

```
  @Controller
  public class AjaxController {

@RequestMapping(value= "user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String login (){ 
   UserRest ur = new UserRest();
   Response r = ur.getUserName(2);
   Gson gs = new Gson();
   String str = gs.toJson(r);
   return str;
}
 }

Response getUserName(int userID){
    Response response = new Response();
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Properties.SERVER_SECURE_URL + "users/" + userID);
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","1Strajk");


            response.setMessageCode(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            if(response.getMessageCode()==Response.MESSAGE_OK) {
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(!total.toString().isEmpty()){
                response.setObject(total.toString());
            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return response;
}
```

Comment: u mean when you don't have  UserRest ur = new UserRest(); it works?

Comment: I call method getUserName and node server doesn't react on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it. I forgot about SSL connection. Before calling rest I called that method:

```
public class SSLUtils {
public static void trustEveryone() {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {}
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }}}, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                context.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```